Scale Background(SpriteRenderer) C#,Unity
When I change the resolution, the camera gets closer to the center and many objects are simply not visible.How can I fix this?screen with wrong sizes. correct size my gamesame problem on other scenes.
I've tried changing different canvas settings, the sprites themselves.I asked the chat, but it didn't work out.settings canvas

If someone encounters such a problem, then use Pixel Perfect Camera.The built-in Unity didn't help me.I wrote my own script based on PixelPerfectCamera which helped me.
using UnityEngine;

public class PixelPerfectCameraManual : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int targetWidth = 736;
    public int targetHeight = 414;
    public int pixelsPerUnit = 30;

    void Start()
    {
        AdjustCameraSize();
    }
    void Update()
    {
        AdjustCameraSize();
    }

    void AdjustCameraSize()
    {
        float targetAspect = (float)targetWidth / targetHeight;
        float windowAspect = (float)Screen.width / Screen.height;

        if (windowAspect >= targetAspect)
        {
            Camera.main.orthographicSize = targetHeight / 2.0f / pixelsPerUnit;
        }
        else
        {
            float differenceInSize = targetAspect / windowAspect;
            Camera.main.orthographicSize = targetHeight / 2.0f / pixelsPerUnit * differenceInSize;
        }
    }
}

